# Nested elements with absolute position in a overflown element bleed out and show

Tags: html, css

This is somewhat annoying. Not sure if it's my fault or if this is a browser bug - both FF and Chrome seem to do it so...

here's the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/UF8n3/

the premise:

div with `overflow-y: auto`

child divs within that, appear fine

children of the child divs (`div.collectibleMiniHead`) with `position: absolute` but no `left`/`top` values (so relative, really) don't remain hidden but are being shown.

I can refactor to use `position: relative` and it works but this does not make the bug/behaviour go away - is this normal / expected, shall I bother submitting it to the mozilla and webkit bugtrackers or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed all four instances of

```
<div style="background:..height: 94px;" /></div>
```

to

```
<div style="background:..height: 94px;"></div>
```

because self-closing and then having another closing tag didn't seem to make much sense.

However, that didn't change anything.

You said:

> children of the child divs
>   (div.collectibleMiniHead) with
>   position: absolute but no left/top
>   values **(so relative, really)**

and

> I can refactor to use position:
>   relative and it works but this does
>   not make the bug/behaviour go away

Simply adding `position: relative` to `div.collectibleMini` makes it work as I think you want it to, and doesn't require much work in refactoring.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/UF8n3/4/) (also with self-closing `divs` fixed)

I think I've either elegantly solved your problem, or alternatively I've got completely the wrong end of the stick. Here's hoping for the former!

Comment: oh I had self-closed divs. nice. thanks be to my new IDE Jetbrain webstorm that I installed a few days ago. on my iPhone ATM but will test fix later on.

Comment: hrm, i had fixed it by changing `position:relative` on the `collectibleMiniHead` and avoiding absolutes but your suggestion of applying it to `collectibleMini` works and is smarter and less limiting, cheers. accepting this even if it does not address the possible browser bug question...

Comment: I think the browsers are doing it right - there's no bug here. I think you'd just forgotten that you need to apply `position: relative` to a parent element (even applying it to your outermost div would fix it) to have `position: absolute` on a child do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding collectibleMiniHead as a child of collectibleMiniBody and `position: relative;` on collectibleMiniBody